# Is matching on patterns faster than if/else in rust?

Tags: rust

Let's say you have an enum

```rust
enum Expr {
 binExp, unExp, Literal, Group 
}
```

And you want to call methods on `Expr`.

Would you rather :

```rust
match Expr { 
 Expr::binExp  => todo!(),
 Expr::unExp   => todo!(),
 Expr::Literal => todo!(),
 Expr::Group   => todo!()
}
```

OR

```rust
if let Expression::binExp = self {
  todo!()
} else if let Expression::unExp = self {
  todo!()
} else if let Expression::Lit = self {
  todo!()
} else if let Expression::Group(e) = self {
  todo!()
} else {
  todo!()
}
```

Stated another way, is `match` a parallel operation? I know `if/else` will go through each expression sequentially, evaluating them as they are encountered as false and finally make a stop.

Do match statements mimic this behavior or do they directly **jump** to the correct pattern? I ask this specifically because `match` can match on multiple patterns, but always select the pattern that matches it first. So it does sound like `match` may be sequential in that regard.

Comment: When built in release mode, both `match` and `if let` chains deploy powerful optimizations to generate the fastest possible code. Nothing is guaranteed, but for the simple cases outlined in the question, I would expect the same (optimal) code to be generated by both.

Comment: Generally yes, but the compiler is made out of eldritch black magic so it will probably figure out how to optimize it to the same result either way. The best option is whichever you feel makes your code most verbose and maintainable.

Comment: @Locke: least verbose and most maintainable surely?